# Format output in bteq in teradata

Tags: sql, unix, teradata

I am using below bteq to fetch data .

```
.Set Separator '|'
.SET TITLEDASHES OFF;
.SET NULL AS ''

.EXPORT REPORT FILE = /app2/test.txt
sel
emp_id,
float_perc,
CAST( 0  AS DECIMAL(18.2) ) AS var
from emp
```

I am getting below output:

```
5|.99|.00
4|.78|.00
```

But we want output in below format:

```
5|0.99|0.00
4|0.78|0.00
```

Can anyone please help on this.
Can we replace |. with |0. in unix (Sun OS) with sed or tee?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a `FORMAT`?

```
sel
emp_id,
float_perc (FORMAT '9.99'),
CAST( 0  AS DECIMAL(18.2) FORMAT '9.99') AS var
from emp
```

Comment: I have tried FORMAT but this is not working. Even i had tried to cast var as below CAST( cast(0 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS varchar(20)) AS var

Comment: Does it change the output at all or are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: I am getting same record but only problem is format. I want record in below format.                                               5|0.99|0.00
4|0.78|0.00

Comment: Perhaps converting it to a varchar.  CAST( float_perc AS VARCHAR(4) FORMAT '9.99')

Comment: Also, I dropped the Z, I think you don't want that in this case.

Comment: @navku You should use a FORMAT matching the datatype & length: e.g. for a DECIMAL(18,2) FORMAT '-(16)9.99'. Regarding your expected out: do you want something like CSV? REPORT is always fixed width, you need to concat all columns with the SELECT (or use TPT)

Comment: I am trying to cast field as below but getting error as "expected something between ( and FORMAT"                                    CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18.2)) FORMAT('ZZZZZZZZZ9.99')  AS AMT,
CAST(INTEREST_RATE AS DECIMAL(18,7)) FORMAT('ZZZZZZZZZ9.9999999') AS INTEREST_MIN